# Hidden colorless spots?

Tags: paper-mario-color-splash

I've noticed that I seem to find between 95-99% of colorless spots in stages, including in Port Prisma.

I'm still near the beginning of the game, are there spots that aren't initially unlocked in stages or are some spots just really hard to see?

Comment: Having said that, I found what I was missing in Port Prisma by sheer chance.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed colourless spots which you can't get the first time you play through a level. Five key examples are Sunglow Ridge, Violet Passage, Mustard Café, Marmalade Valley and Mondo Woods - even if you could get all the spots, there is one key colourless item or area which requires the Big Paint Stars to colour them in.